# Workflow appears corrupted

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow created in SPD 2013 and running on SharePoint 2013. It's been working ok but lately, when I open the workflow, many of the Conditions and other settings are blank or missing and I have to laboriously re-create all the missing elements. I know this is not an issue with SPD needing a cache-clearing; I've already done that.

In the snip below you can see where the opening condition of the Stage is missing, and the Loop values are missing. In fact, I cannot simply re-add the values in the loop -- SPD won't hold the values. I have to completely recreate the Loop.

[image]

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: This workflow has seven Stages. In all of them, the leading Condition and the Loop conditions in each Stage are missing. The rest of the elements are ok and unaffected.

Comment: did you change the column name from where you are fetching the value? what type of column is it?

Comment: Haven't made any changes to columns. The conditions are all simple text-based, for example, loop while: ManagerStatus Equals Active.